# User Defined Function to determine whether string contains a substring

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code which is currently returning 0 regardless if the string contains the substring or not. It should return 1 if the substring is found.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.checkLetters (@MESSAGE VARCHAR)
RETURNS INTEGER
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @value INTEGER;
    IF @MESSAGE LIKE '%findMe%'
        SET @value = 1
    ELSE
        SET @value = 0
    RETURN @value
END;
```

I also tried using `charindex` in my `IF` statement to no avail. Am I missing something simple here?

Testing like so:

```
SELECT dbo.checkletters('dLHLd');
```

Comment: Is it `sql server` or `mysql`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `(@MESSAGE VARCHAR(max))` as a input parameter. or instead of max specify the length, currently in your function it is only 1. That is the issue.

Comment: Ah, well, that is embarrassing. Cheers for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Modify your function as given below:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.checkLetters (@MESSAGE VARCHAR(max))
RETURNS INTEGER
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @value INTEGER;
   DECLARE  @ExpressionToFind VARCHAR(50)
   SET @ExpressionToFind = 'findme'
   IF @MESSAGE  LIKE '%' + @ExpressionToFind + '%'
    SET @value = 1
ELSE
    SET @value = 0
  RETURN @value
END;
```

The problem was in your input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your function could be rewritten as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.checkLetters (@MESSAGE VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS BIT
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(CHARINDEX('findMe', @MESSAGE) AS BIT);
END
```

`CHARINDEX` will find position of `@MESSAGE` in given string and if it's higher than 1, it will output 1 (bit operator).